# Can default tikz options be altered?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing a document with lots of `tikz` figures. Every single one of them starts with `\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]`. Is it possible to set `line join=round` and `line cap=round` at the beginning of the document so I don't have to keep setting these options myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a global style, so to speak, that will be applied to every path by writing this in the preamble, inside of the `\tikzset`:

```
\tikzset{
    every path/.style={line join=round, line cap=round}
}
```